# File too big for VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

This is my Situation:

I got a big excel file (1 table, text only, about 55 MB, about 1000 rows, a lot of columns).

I need to delete EVERYTHING BUT the following:

- Columns 1-5 from each row
- all cells containing a specific string (let it be "hello") this is not an exact search, the cell can contain more text, in that case the whole cell is important.

Thanks to my superior google skills I found part of a solution:
Delete all cells with a grey background. So first I am colouring all cells grey, then manually switch colour for columns 1-5 and then with conditional formatting change colour for all cells containing "hello".

This is the code to find the ColourCode:

```
Sub FindColor()
MsgBox ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Sub
```

This is the code to empty all grey cells:

```
Sub ClearGrey()
Dim rng As Range 
For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
rng.ClearContents
End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

So you probably see multiple mistakes already and i am open for a different approach.

If you think my solution is usable I have the following problem:

It works for small files; unfortunately in my file Excel kills itself after a few minutes without any work done.

So here are my questions:

- How do I lighten the load for excel?
- Does my approach even make sense?
- Is there maybe a super easy way I just can't see?

Thanks a lot already,

Raphael

I forgot to say that I am working on a Mac

Comment: Look at using `enitrecolumn.delete` but before hand looping from `usedrange.columns.count` to 5 and checking using something like `countif` for your search string or even something like `if  ActiveSheet.columns(6).find("hello") is nothing then  ActiveSheet.columns(6).entirecolumn.delete` and have calcs set to manual

Comment: [Please]don't[put][tags]in[titles]

Comment: Please refer to [How to increase the execution speed of my VBA macro code? (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47261539/7690982)